# I don't understand how to use "sort" properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

```
data = [2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 10, 9]
i = data.sort()
print(i)

>>>None

data = [2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 10, 9]
data.sort()
print(data)

>>>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10]
```

I think 2 codes are same each other
Why results are different?

Comment: "Why results are different?" - because in the first example you're printing `i`, but in the second one you're printing `data`. You're getting different results because `i` is not the same as `data` since `data.sort()` doesn't return (a modified version of) `data`

Comment: `data.sort()` sorts `data` and doesn't return a result. By contrast, `sorted(data)` would return a new sorted version, without sorting `data`.

Comment: Note that in your first example, if you had added `print(data)` after the `print(i)`, you'd have noticed that `data` was successfully sorted.

Comment: From python.org: "Python lists have a built-in list.sort() method that modifies the list in-place", i.e. it doesn't return a new list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the .sort() method doesn't return a new list, rather it mutates the same list. If you want to return a new list, you can use sorted(data) and set that to a new variable.

E.g.,

```
data = [2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 10, 9]
i = sorted(data)
print(i)
>>>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10]
```